# Gnuplot legend with two boxes/groups and custom heading

Tags: gnuplot, legend

I have two types of data/plot and I want to group them for clarification. For example, lets say I have this four data plots

```
set key box
pl x, x**2, sin(x), cos(x)
```

And the legend box comes out to be something like
[image]

But what I want is something like this, (with two box for each group and a custom heading for each group)

[image: what_I_want]

How do I do this? Is this type of legend possible with gnuplot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear, that there is no bulit-in solution in `Gnuplot` for that. But you can try with `multiplot`:

```
set key box
set key width 3

set multiplot

set key at screen 0.45,0.95
set key title "Polynomial"

plot[-10:10][-20:100] x t 'x', x**2 t 'x^2'

set key at screen 0.65,0.95
set key title "Trigonometrical"

plot[-10:10][-20:100] sin(x) lc 3, cos(x) lc 4

unset multiplot
```

[image: Result]

**EDIT**

As Eldrad wrote, you can fine tuning this solution by setting the margins and unsetting the `tics` and `border` of the second plot. Eg.:

```
set key box
set key width 3

set multiplot

set lmargin screen 0.05
set rmargin screen 0.95
set bmargin screen 0.05
set tmargin screen 0.95
set key at screen 0.45,0.95
set key title "Polynomial"
set tics
set border

plot[-10:10][-20:100] x t 'x', x**2 t 'x^2'

set key at screen 0.65,0.95
set key title "Trigonometrical"
unset tics
set border 0

plot[-10:10][-20:100] sin(x) lc 3, cos(x) lc 4

unset multiplot
```

Comment: Good approach, but it has one flaw: All tics are printed twice (and hence appear as bold). In order to avoid that, you would need to call `unset tics` before the second plot, and to fix the margins beforehand so that the borders do overlap.

Comment: @Eldrad yes you are right.

Comment: This with some manual adjustment exactly did what I wanted. Also thanks making me aware of `key title`

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward option to create two keys, but there are definitely several workarounds that will need manual adjustment. One approach could be creating a two-column key:

```
set key maxrows 3 width 5
plot keyentry t "Polynomial", x t "x", x**2 t "x²", keyentry t "Trigonometry", sin(x), cos(x)
```

[image]

Another approach might be based on the `multiple keys` section in the manual.